# I am Using angular 6 and i have an issue that happened suddenly when i was login the element in the nav bar was changing and now it is not

Tags: angular

مرحبا بك
    {{authService.decodedToken?.unique_name | titlecase}}
    
    
      
        ملفى الشخصى
        
      
        تسجيل الخروج
    
  
  
    
    
    تفضل
      بالدخول

Comment: Check if you has an error in console (In Angular an error break the execution). BTW, Angular 6? if you're panning change to a newer Angular version, take account that the "httpClient" has changed (and the Rxjs)

Comment: There is no error in console and I am planning to change into a newer version I think ngcc makes this issue because I have error in ngcc